# Downgrade C# 6.0 to 5.0 Code

Tags: c#

I had code written in VS 2015 (C# 6)  now due to some reasons I want to downgrade it to C# 5 can anyone help me?

```
var idpEntityId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier)?.Issuer ?? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Issuer;
```

I converted to

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier).Issuer : null; 
??
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Issuer : null;
```

But I am still getting Error on `??`

Please could anyone help ?

Comment: `?.` is a null conditional operator which only exist in C# 6 & above, you need to convert it manually as null-checking if-condition. But leave null-coalescing `??` intact.

Comment: This is not a code writing service you should try do this yourself

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not code translation service, even for different versions of same language.

Comment: I am not asking any service here, I am not using C# 6 I don't know the new features of the C# just seeking help.

Answer (score 2):

Your one-liner

```
var idpEntityId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier)?.Issuer ?? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Issuer;
```

would translate to the following construct in previous versions of C#:

```
var logoutNameIdentifier = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier);
var lniIssuer = logoutNameIdentifier != null ? logoutNameIdentifier.Issuer : null;
var idpEntityId = lniIssuer;
if (idpEntityId == null)
{
    var ctNameIdentifier = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (ctNameIdentifier != null)
        idpEntityId = ctNameIdentifier.Issuer;
}
```

Quite a bit more complicated. Therefore I thought of writing the following extension method:

```
public static U NonNullMap<T, U>(this T t, Func<T, U> m)
{
    return t != null ? m(t) : default(U);
}
```

With this, the code then looks as follows:

```
var idpEntityId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current
                                 .FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier)
                                 .NonNullMap(lni => lni.Issuer);
if (idpEntityId == null)
    idpEntityId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current
                                 .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
                                 .NonNullMap(ni => ni.Issuer);
```

Still verbose but at least more readable, in my opinion.

*Edit:* If the `??` operator works in C# 5.0, you can shorten the code down to:

```
var idpEntityId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current
                                 .FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier)
                                 .NonNullMap(lni => lni.Issuer) ??
                  ClaimsPrincipal.Current
                                 .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
                                 .NonNullMap(ni => ni.Issuer);
```